# what fuse for an electric circuit tester

Tags: fuses

Cannot seem to get a clear answer on the web. I have a mains tester with a blown 100mA fuse (glass) do I replace it with a quick blow fuse or a time delay fuse. Common sense would say a quick blow fuse. There are no Q or T marks on the existing fuse.

Comment: What does the internet say about the model you are using (or the user manual)?

Comment: If you are testing mains voltage of any type and it's using a basic glass fuse then the tester is likely very poorly designed.  HRC fuses are much safer.

Comment: Andy - It is an old tester and I do not have the manual nor can I find it on the internet. Most things on the internet do say it is a good reliable tester hence why I still use it.

Comment: David a HRC fuse usually have a much Higher Rupture Capacity. Why would I want to put a HRC fuse in the tester ?

Comment: HRC fuses are designed to still blow safely (without exploding) even if they are overloaded much higher than their rated current.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a voltage tester (or any type of test equipment), you should probably use a quick blow fuse for safety reasons unless it says otherwise.

Comment: Trivia.  The real purpose of the fuse is to prevent fires.  Preventing electric shock to the operator (and other animals) is not the purpose of the fuse.

Comment: jBot thanks for the confirmation of my own thoughts. Nick - I always understood a fuse was to protect a circuit and equipment. I would have thought a mains circuit tester to be a piece of equipment and therefore needs protecting as does the user !

Comment: If this answer is correct, than you should mark it accepted.